# Why am I receiving 4 broadcasts of android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE on cold boot?

Tags: android, widget

When I boot my phone from cold, I'm receiving 4 broadcasts of the intent `android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE`.  This is causing my app to do 4 times the processing it needs to and I'm trying to work out the best way to handle this.  However, I'm wondering why I'm getting 4 in the first place?  Shouldn't the system only send one intent?

Comment: AFAIK, these broadcasts are triggered in part by the home screen. Try switching temporarily to a third-party home screen and see what the behavior is. Beyond that, one optimization would be to stash a `lastUpdatedTime` in a static data member. If, on an update, `lastUpdatedTime` is too old, or is `null` (meaning your process had been terminated since the last update), do the real work, otherwise skip it.

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare, that's exactly the approach I've been taking.  I'll see if I can get different behaviour from a different home screen.